# How can I get my nodemailer email as a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I'm using the nodemailer module with node.js and have done the following:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'email@gmail.com',
    pass: 'mypassword'
  }
});
```

To declare the transporter. My question is if I can access the email - 'user' as a variable to save me updating it everywhere if I need to change it. I've tried to do

`console.log(transporter.auth.user);`

but I get 'Cannot read property 'user' of undefined.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is :

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'email@gmail.com',
    pass: 'mypassword'
  }
});
console.log(transporter.transporter.auth.credentials);
```

Will give you :

```
Object {pass: "mypassword", user: "email@gmail.com"}
```

---

Like our friend Sapher stated in the comment :

```
console.log(transporter.options.auth);
```

will also return the same `Object` (containing the `pass` & `user`)

Comment: @Sapher thank you very much, this works perfectly. Mind explaining why it is that the .options or transporter.transporter is actually needed?

Comment: do `console.log(transporter);` you will see it returns an object. `transporter` and `options` are both keys of that object.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a variable for that.

```
const email = "myemail@gmail.com";

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
       user: email,
       pass: 'mypassword'
    }
});

// ...
console.log(email);
```

Comment: I could, but can I access the property from the object? I'm sure it must be possible.

Comment: @MatthewChristopher you can... check my answer ;)